# get only selective data from class bytes python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have a bytes type string which is something like this

```
"b'----------------------------677775754061095226512728\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"mofoso.xlsx\"\\r\\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\\r\\n\\r\\nname,Password,Access key ID,Secret access key,Console login link\\nhttps://935.com,https://935463.com,https://935463.com,https://935.com,https://935463345537.com\\n213,132,123,14,1234\\n213,132,123,14,1234\\n213,132,123,14,1234\\r\\n----------------------------677775754061095226512728--\\r\\n'"
```

and I want only data from this like

```
"b' name,Password,Access key ID,Secret access key,Console login link\\nhttps://935.com,https://935463.com,https://935463.com,https://935.com,https://935463345537.com\\n213,132,123,14,1234\\n213,132,123,14,1234\\n213,132,123,14,1234\\r\\n '"
```

how I can achieve this ?

Comment: `myBytes.split(b"\r\n")[-3]` seems like it would work

Comment: @JoranBeasley  can you please tell the logic for this?  working perfectly fine